# Problem in using text link to open widget chat of tawk.to ..Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tawk.to

Problem in using text link to open widget chat of tawk.to
this link is not working in my site to open chat widget.
 Click to Chat 
I have made that site using wordpress and used elementor pulgin for pages.
And whenever i add this link in the text and updating it showe 403 error.
Can you help me in rectifying this error? or any alternative to open chat
widget?

Answer (score 0):

This one is used for live chat : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-live-chat-support/

Comment: i need this for tawk.to.